# XMLHttpRequest referrer and iframe

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, referer

Page `A` contains javascripts function executing `XMLHttpRequest`. Page `A` loads page `B` in iframe. Page `B` executes `parent.makeRequest()` function which in turn executes the `XHR` request. I expect the referrer/origin of the `XHR` request to be page `B`, however it is page `A`. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be page B? The XHR request is being made by page A.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot control the value of the `Referer` header.

Some HTTP headers can be adjusted when making XHR requests using the [`setRequestHeader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method) method.  However, the `Referer` header is specifically excepted.  From the specifications:

> The above headers [including `Referer`] are controlled by the user agent to let it control those aspects of transport. This guarantees data integrity to some extent.

You could, however, set a custom header.  For instance, you could use `X-Referer`, if this suits your application:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Referer', location.href);
```

Comment: updated link: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-setrequestheader()-method